# Arzela-Ascoli equivalent theorems

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

The following theorems are equivalent? Is the Theorem 2 false?

Theorem 1 [(Arzela-Ascoli):](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem)
Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $C(X)$ denote the space of continuous functions $f: X \to \mathbb C$ endowed with the sup norm $\|\cdot \|_\infty$. Then $S \subseteq C(X)$ is relatively compact if and only if it is **pointwise bounded** and equicontinuous.

Theorem 2:
Let $X$ be a compact metric space and let $C(X)$ denote the space of continuous functions $f: X \to \mathbb C$ endowed with the sup norm $\|\cdot \|_\infty$. Then $S \subseteq C(X)$ is relatively compact if and only if it is **pointwise bounded at some point** and equicontinuous.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two variants are not equivalent, and "Theorem 2" is false.

Consider $X = \{0,1\}\subset \mathbb{R}$, and $S = \{ f_z : z \in \mathbb{C}\}$, where $f_z(p) = p\cdot z$. Then $S$ is equicontinuous and bounded at $0$, but not relatively compact.

"Theorem 2" becomes true, and the two theorems equivalent if $X$ is additionally required to be connected, for under that condition, the boundedness at one point implies the uniform boundedness on the entire space.

Comment: I see it now by the connectedness. Thanks for your solution!